# Migrate from Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python

I'm working with the app engine platform, python 2.5.x and Django, and I'm looking for other solution to host my web app.

Can you suggest me blog, or websites who explain how to install a such platform.

Answer (score 2):

Support for Python 2.5 has been deprecated and you should move only install version 2.7 upwards on Google Engine.

These are both documented excellently at [Developers Google](http://developers.google.com/):

- [Install Python 2.7 on Google App Engine](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/)
- [Django on Google App Engine](http://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django)